# Sending input values on the fly to API's

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my application, there are some input text fields where data is being populated by the application. These fields are editable by the user.

I want to send the edited values to the API, but the application is sending the old value (instead of the edited one). I am using angular 1.

Here's some of the code I am using:

```
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="value1"></td> 
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="value2"></td> 
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="VALUE3"></td>
```

And another thing I have tried:

```
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng- keyup="value1"></td>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: use ng-keyup event to get the last edited data;

Comment: @SultanKhan:Tried <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-
      keyup="value1"></td>  not working

Comment: <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng- keyup="getValue()"  ng-model="value1"></td>

and call this function and you can get the value.